# Swift Code Improvement

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm quite new to Swift and Xcode 6 and just made an app. Now I'm trying to improve my code and I know there's a way to make this code way shorter, I just don't know how.

```
button1.layer.cornerRadius = 10
button1.layer.borderWidth = 1
button1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

button2.layer.cornerRadius = 10
button2.layer.borderWidth = 1
button2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

button3.layer.cornerRadius = 10
button3.layer.borderWidth = 1
button3.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

button4.layer.cornerRadius = 10
button4.layer.borderWidth = 1
button4.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

button5.layer.cornerRadius = 10
button5.layer.borderWidth = 1
button5.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an array of all the buttons, and then loop through them.

```
var buttons = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5]

for button in buttons {
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
}
```